# How to make JS click with poltergeist webdriver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, acceptance-testing, poltergeist, capybara-webkit

When I run test with chrome driver - it passes.

When I run it with poltergeist - it tries to make click with format HTML and I have error:

```
 ActionController::UnknownFormat:
   ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

**controller.rb**

  `def features
    newspaper = Newspaper.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render locals: { newspaper: newspaper } }
    end
  end`

**view.html.haml**

`= link_to features_newspaper_path(newspaper), class: %w(qa-edit-features), format: 'js', remote: true`

**feature_spec.rb**

    `it 'enable newspaper hilsninger features', js: true do
      find('.qa-edit-features').click
    end`

**spec_helper.rb**

`require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
if ENV['BROWSER'] == 'google-chrome'
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
else
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a JS error on your page (or use of ES2015+ methods not supported by Poltergeist) causing the JS parsing to fail and the rails UJS handlers to never be installed.  Make sure your Poltergeist driver registration config (https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization) has `js_errors: true` in it and it should show you the JS error.